# How do I autorun a file when a USB drive is inserted in another computer?

Tags: windows-7, usb, autorun

Some guy in my class shut my pc down while I was working on something. I want to get him back by automatically running a file after having inserted a USB in his USB port. The computers at our school run windows 7 and are even allowed to open cmd as an administrator. Is there a relatively easy way to do that? (And I have tried shutting it down remotely, but I I just got a response saying: "Access denied (5)")

Comment: Windows 7 and on don't autorun anything that comes via USB. Only content from CD/DVD can be autorun. Most PCs are configured to not autorun *anything* anyways so good luck with that.

Comment: Welcome to Superuser. Please try to keep non-relevant details out of the questions, as this is more of a Q&A site, and not a forum.

Answer (score 1):

Windows will not automatically run anything that is "executable" from removable media.
Actually in XP and Vista (I think) this used to be possible by default, but as this was a major virus-vector Microsoft updated those Windows versions via WindowsUpdate to block the auto-running of executable content. (Later Windows versions have it disabled as factory-default.)
Launching an executable can still be done, but requires the user to manually start it, which defeats your purpose.
Only media-files (movies/music) can still auto-play using the autorun.inf file placed in the root-folder of the medium. Executables can be mentioned in that file as well, but that just sets the default-action to use, when the user clicks it. It will not auto-launch by itself.